# Converting Rails 2 plugin to Rails 3 gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3

So there's this great plugin I've gotten used to using in my Rails 2 projects called Bootstrapper. It essentially duplicates the functionality of the seeds.rb file, but I like it because it lets you break up your bootstrap process into concise chunks.

Anyway, I've gone so far as to fork the project and attempt to turn it into a Rails 3 gem. I've been able to get the gem to initialize and register the rake tasks and generators OK. However, I'm running into a problem with the Bootstrapper class itself. It won't load in the Rails project unless it's in a module.

That is, if I place the Bootstrapper class in a file by itself and require that file in my Railtie, then in my Rails app, it can't find the Bootstrapper class. If I put the class in a module and call Bootstrapper::Bootstrapper everything is peachy.

The code that actually requires the Bootstrapper class is this:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load :active_record do
  require 'bootstrapper/bootstrapper'
end
```

The source is available here:
http://github.com/jrmehle/bootstrapper/tree/make_gem

Answer (score 0):

Autoload paths actually has an annoying feature of following filesystem paths.  For example in your lib or extras (depending on what you autoload) you might have the following file structure:

```
lib/bootstrapper/bootstrapper.rb
# in this case, Bootstrapper::Bootstrapper.class = Class in rails c
# ie: you don't get a NameError exception
```

More specifically,

```
lib/bootstrappers/bootstrapper.rb
# Bootstrapper::Bootstrapper => NameError
# Bootstrappers::Bootstrapper => works
```

If you really want the other way, you can move everything into your lib/bootstrapper.rb source file but meh, I don't like doing that, that's not how gems are organized.  In rails3, you'll find the autoloading pretty nice once you use modules everywhere (which can be painful).

Rails3 uses /extras instead of /lib but it's not required, it's just the default (commented out) from `rails new`.  To switch, you just autoload extras instead of lib.